# Django GROUP BY including unnecessary columns?

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

I have Django code as follows

`qs = Result.objects.only('time')
 qs = qs.filter(organisation_id=1) 
 qs = qs.annotate(Count('id'))`

And it gets translated into the following SQL:

`SELECT "myapp_result"."id", "myapp_result"."time", COUNT("myapp_result"."id") AS "id__count" FROM "myapp_result" WHERE "myapp_result"."organisation_id" = 1 GROUP BY "myapp_result"."id", "myapp_result"."organisation_id", "myapp_result"."subject_id", "myapp_result"."device_id", "myapp_result"."time", "myapp_result"."tester_id", "myapp_result"."data"`

As you can see, the GROUP BY clause starts with the field I intended (id) but then it goes on to list all the other fields as well. Is there any way I can persuade Django not to specify all the individual fields like this?

As you can see, even with `.only('time')` that doesn't stop Django from listing all the other fields anyway, but only in this GROUP BY clause.

The reason I want to do this is to avoid [the issue described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117933/django-db-error-could-not-identify-an-equality-operator-for-type-json-when-tryi) where PostgreSQL doesn't support annotation when there's a JSON field involved. I don't want to drop native JSON support (so I'm not actually using django-jsonfield). The query works just fine if I manually issue it without the reference to `"myapp_result"."data"` (the only JSON field on the model). So if I could just persuade Django not to refer to it, I'd be fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`only` only defers the loading of certain fields, i.e. it allows for lazy loading of big or unused fields. It should generally not be used unless you know exactly what you're doing and why you need it, as it is nothing more than a performance booster than often *decreases* performance with improper use.

What you're looking for is `values()` (or `values_list()`), which actually excludes certain fields instead of just lazy loading. This will return a dictionary (or list) instead of a model instance, but this is the only way to tell Django to not take other fields into account:

```
qs = (Result.objects.filter_by(organisation_id=1)
            .values('time').annotate(Count('id')))
```